# Modeling conditional, binary data

Tags: conditional-expectation

I'm trying identify a good model for what I think is a fairly straightforward task. I have two binary dependents (A & B) where the occurrence of B is contingent on the outcome of A. Meaning if A=0 B=0, but if A=1 then B=0 or 1 (so B=1, always means A=1). I want a test that will help me evaluate the effect of the independent stimulus on the occurrence of B, but with B contingent on the occurrence of A. I know negative binomial or hurdle models could help me address the effect of the stimulus on A and B separately, but I don't know if they can process the conditional term. So maybe someone could help me figure out if there's a way to do that with those models, or if I need totally different one.  I'll be using R to execute whatever model I come up with. Thanks!

Comment: I think it all boils down to analyzing the subset of data for which the "A" event occurred. If you were evaluating a chemotherapy agent, you would have to state that you are considering people with a diagnosis of cancer.

Answer (score 1):

If your task is just to evaluate the effect of $A=1$ on $B$ then you are merely looking to estimate the probability $\mathbb{P}(B|A=1)$.  Since $B$ is binary, it makes sense to estimate this conditional probability using a corresponding sampling proportion.  So I would suggest you look at cases where $A=1$ and then observe trials $B_1, ..., B_n \sim \text{IID Bern}(\theta_1)$.  You can then estimate:

$$\hat{\mathbb{P}}(B|A=1) = \hat{\theta}_1 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=n}^n B_i.$$

You can also obtain an interval estimate of this conditional probability if you want, using standard methods applying to Bernoulli trials.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this basically reduces to logistic regression in most cases.

Comment: Not quite - the logistic transform does not allow zero probabilities, so it would not allow the required condition that $\mathbb{P}(B = 0| A = 0) =1$.